# Logout in Azure AD B2C Android using MSAL

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

i have integrated  `Azure AD B2C` on my mobile App using `MSAL library`. I have created the user flows for `SignIn and SignUp`. I'am getting the access token once the authentication is success. so i have  my logout button designed on my Mobile App on one of my Activity Page, so once i click on my logout button designed on App, i need to get the user `signedOut` from the App. so how can we do the `SignOut` in AZURE AD B2C MSAL on Android?

is it ok even if i clear the access token saved on my preference? or is there any other way to signout from Azure side provideb by `MSAL` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSAL library provides [a logout method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript#sign-out) that clears the cache in browser storage and sends a sign-out request to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). Request will be done against the `end_session_endpoint` URL obtained from the [B2C policy metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#validate-signature). Keep in mind [single sign out is supported only by custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview#sign-out) and that it's scoped to the same browser, not device.

For a Native Android mobile app please use the [signout function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-android#sign-out-a-user) in Ms Document

Comment: Krishna - Currently this is for the Native Mobile Apps and that too implemented using MSAL for mobile apps. so how will be able to logout from my mobile device?

Comment: Krishna - I assume, that is for the web side implementation. Currently i was asking about the `signOut` Process on Native Android Devices from `AZURE AD B2C MSAL`

Comment: Hi @vinayak, Please let me know my updated answer helps.

Comment: Krishna - It was working fine for me. I have followed the Link Provided by you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this user from the cache, you must call [`removeAccount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-android-b2c) for each policy.

```
PublicClientApplication publicClient = MyApplication.getInstance().getPublicClient();
User currentUser = Helpers.getUserByPolicy(publicClient.getUsers(), Constant.SIGN_UP_POLICY);
publicClient.remove(currentUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load account using publicClientApplication 
private fun loadAccounts(mMultipleAccountApp: IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication) {
        mMultipleAccountApp.getAccounts(object: IPublicClientApplication.LoadAccountsCallback {
            override fun onTaskCompleted(result: List<IAccount>) {
                val accountList: List<IAccount> = result
                removeAccounts(mMultipleAccountApp, accountList)
            }

            override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
               Log.d("Error",exception.message)
            }
        })
    }


//call remove account
private fun removeAccounts(
        mMultipleAccountApp: IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication,
        accountList: List<IAccount>
    ) {
        val removeCallback =
            object : IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication.RemoveAccountCallback {
                override fun onRemoved() {
                    // Redirect to login
                    }

                override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
                     Log.d("Error",exception.message)
                }
            }

        B2CUser.signOutAsync(
            accountList,
            mMultipleAccountApp, removeCallback
        )

    }
```